# Unable to establish TCP connections with server

Tags: linux, curl, tcp

I have 2 centOS-7 machines say machine A,B. 
Machine A have a server listening on port 80. When i run curl-loader(for load testing purpose) with 2000 request per second in the same machine, all the request is hitting the server, i checked 'ss -s' command and open TCP sockets is more than 2000.

But my problem is when i run curl-loader in machine B and try to hit server A only few requests are reaching server, remaining all are dropping out.
in machine B 'ss -s' command returns 2K+ value. but in machine A 'ss -s' command will return only value 25-30. Remaining all request are returned are TCP-CONNECT error

Comment: Sounds like that server is throttled. That makes sense in many situations to protect the system from overload. If that server is a http server for example, there is a max_connections config directive. You would have to share more details for us to give more specific help.

Comment: sorry i forget to mention that in my question. My server is squid proxy server and there is no maximum connection limits. When i hit squid from same machine all requests are served, but from another machine all request are not reaching.

As i mentioned above in my question when requests comes from another machine not enough sockets are opened

Comment: Then that points towards a throttling on network level, so by a package filter ("firewall"). Same motivation, different level.

Answer (score 0):

@arkascha is probably right. Some throttling is happening. I would only add that the throttling could be in the network, in the server OR in the client. Any of them could be throttling the number of connections.

It's better to test it without any squid or high level software. You can just do:

(On server) $ echo hello | nc -l -k 10000

(On client) $ for ((i=0; i<2000; i++)); do nc :10000 & done

This will create a "mini" TCP server on the server machine on port 10000. Anyone that connects to that server will receive the message "hello".

Then from the client, you can create 2000 (almost simultaneous) TCP connections to the server on port 10000.

If the connections are successfully established, then the throttling is probably at the "proxy" level. If the connections appear throttled, then the throttling is likely at the firewall or network level.